# Pulp : What does lpDot() does, How to use it

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I am trying to generate an equation via `lpDot()`, Such as

```
PulpVar = [x1,x2]

Constants = [5,6]
```

then doing dot product as:

```
model += lpDot(PulpVar, Constants)
```

Form what I understand this should generate an equation as `x1*5+x2*6`

but I am getting `lpAffineExpression` as output and the lp file so generated is empty

Comment: pulp.lpDot is SumProduct, gives `[x0] * [w0] + [x1] * [w1] + [x2] * [w2]`, where `w` is your constants

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> lpDot() – given two lists of the form [a1, a2, …, an] and [ x1, x2, …,
>   xn] will construct a linear epression to be used as a constraint or
>   variable [ref](https://pypi.org/project/PuLP/)

So, if you use with constants, lpDot() will return dot product, that is a `<class 'pulp.pulp.LpAffineExpression'>`:

```
import pulp

x1 = [1]
x2 = [2]

X = [x1,x2]
Constants = [5, 6]

model = pulp.lpDot(X, Constants)
print(model, type(model))
```

Output:

```
17 <class 'pulp.pulp.LpAffineExpression'>
```

If you quant the equation `x1*5+x2*6` you should use `LpVariable` like this:

```
import pulp


PulpVar1 = pulp.LpVariable('x1')
PulpVar2 = pulp.LpVariable('x2')
Constants = [13, 2]

model = pulp.lpDot([PulpVar1, PulpVar2], Constants)
print(model, type(model))
```

Output:

```
5*x1 + 6*x2 <class 'pulp.pulp.LpAffineExpression'>
```

Comment: So, how to generate a list of lpvariables from a multi dim dictionary, is some function to generate lists of lp variables. This thing required as lists supports slicing which is helpfull in matrix multiplications, thus avoiding for loops.

i dont want to loop over dic varls to create a list