# Solving Model with pulp python

Tags: python, pulp

I have been struggling with solving the following problem:
I have some values stored in variable **returns**, and I want to multiply them by a weight (**x_vars**)in order to make the sum of the products and obtain the value of the variable **target_return**. As the following equation:

[image: $$\sum_{i=0}^{n}(returns_i\cdot x_var_i) = target_return$$]

I am struggling with the answer returned, as it saying x_13 = 1. But is not correct. I have tried to do it with normal constrains and eslastic but I get no correct answer. I have a tolerance of let's say 0.01% of error.

Any guess?

Thanks

```
import pulp as plp
# Name model
# set variables   
target_return = 0.0204185791833761
returns = [0.025865338474480914,
 0.031617753987556174,
 0.017530329404997325,
 -0.0008543358059154293,
 0.010510143115372461,
 0.012048338516174262,
 0.04959181591738604,
 0.06059545751936519,
 0.05926623356137273,
 0.058971753714631814,
 0.03442022388647947,
 0.013688974565667422,
 0.02104075216985901,
 -0.0021299262578251543,
 0.017882182143459602,
 0.018964184657020766,
 0.005792320704504306,
 0.018823216764509265,
 -0.0015860431556348198,
 0.008352716776521163,
 0.030728674721250515,
 0.016529301951210496,
 0.0184734317514465,
 -0.0008822232596910062,
 0.010912806711330658,
 0.023530497410194418,
 0.0378090116601979,
 0.009456335242604919,
 0.005556382185357922,
 0.020013334218681678,
 0.05852489326632937,
 0.047988175193893645,
 0.016134386609760742,
 0.014350880108888964,
 0.006756782462879585]

# Initialize model
prob=plp.LpProblem("Find Weights Model", plp.LpMinimize)
x_vars=plp.LpVariable.dicts("x", range(0, len(returns)), 0, 1)
for index in range(len(returns)):
    x_vars[index].setInitialValue(0.5)

#Set problem
prob += plp.lpSum([x_vars[i] for i in x_vars]) == 1

#Set constrain
constrain=plp.LpConstraint(plp.lpSum(
    [returns[i]*x_vars[i] for i in range(0, len(returns))]), rhs=target_return)
# To use standard constrain uncomment following line
#prob.addConstraint(constrain)
# To use elastic constrain uncomment following line
elastic_constrain=constrain.makeElasticSubProblem(penalty = 500000,proportionFreeBoundList  =[0.001,0.0001])
prob.extend(elastic_constrain) 


prob.solve(plp.PULP_CBC_CMD(msg=True, warmStart=True))
final_weights={}
for v in prob.variables():
    final_weights[v.name]=v.varValue

print("Status:", plp.LpStatus[prob.status])

final_weights
```

Possible solutions:

```
solution1 = [0.00962135141677065,
0.00962135141677065,
0.0277264834687149,
0.0297957188693739,
0.0324961558793471,
0.030826881062523,
0.0306009427392119,
0.0250863577897657,
0.0234700849350161,
0.0236653284777789,
0.0237085827820698,
0.0273148420035226,
0.0303599573647406,
0.0292800893464517,
0.0326835213770196,
0.0297440370126145,
0.0295851066643113,
0.0315198597719625,
0.0296058126214705,
0.0326036329340179,
0.0311437752841399,
0.0278570759221869,
0.0299427552142207,
0.0296571910611703,
0.0325002521378998,
0.0307677356659276,
0.0289143823239777,
0.0268170787933395,
0.0309816698637205,
0.0315545156635921,
0.0294310019878726,
0.023774220455596,
0.0253219090166822,
0.0300007623180508,
0.0302627332639599]

solution2 = [0.0291039150753347,
0.0291039150753347,
0.028739103831572,
0.0296325128619877,
0.0307984495156388,
0.0300777243941537,
0.0299801757193628,
0.027599206714805,
8.34695965451632E-05,
0.0269856659961344,
0.0270043421537945,
0.0285613748092319,
0.0298761263170002,
0.0294098868961038,
0.0308793458966854,
0.0296102001652331,
0.0295415791679557,
0.0303769265588311,
0.0295505206943934,
0.0308448536374279,
0.0302145485146196,
0.0287954885757358,
0.0296959977222549,
0.0295727013961937,
0.030800217918514,
0.0300521885203749,
0.0292519883685474,
0.0283464607865791,
0.0301445556616913,
0.030391887092054,
0.0294750434895131,
0.0270326804365011,
0.0277009088398652,
0.0297210421051448,
0.0298341506415484]
```

In excel, I've got the solutions using the following configuration:
[image]

Comment: This link might be useful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57309541/pulp-what-does-lpdot-does-how-to-use-it. Otherwise, you can use numpy.dot.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I've checked your answer but I dont see how it can help. If you execute my code, you may find that if  you check prob content, you will already see that there are the equations which makes sense. I know it has an answer as I've tested it in excel previously.

Comment: Do you know what the correct answer should be? This would help debug what the problem is.

Comment: I've changed the target_return, that I set it up wrong before (sorry) and two possible answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution you got from pulp (CBC) is correct, it's just not the same as the one from Excel. To confirm the constraints are respected you can do the following:

```py
solution3 = [x.value() for x in x_vars.values()]

# objective: 0.0204185791833761
sum(val*returns[i] for i, val in enumerate(solution1))
# 0.02053629325573023
sum(val*returns[i] for i, val in enumerate(solution3))
# 0.02039816058427895

# constraint:
sum(val for i, val in enumerate(solution1))
# 0.9782431569057903
sum(val for i, val in enumerate(solution3))
# 0.999999999
```

In fact, the solution from pulp is closer to the objective and respects a lot better the constraint of sum()=1.

Comment: So it's just a fact that I dont know how to check the answers? Let me check it